The maximum area of a pentagon inside a circle
I thought of this problem, which is nothing new, but searching over here and elsewhere I found nothing explicit or satisfactory. So I decided to try to solve it by my own, but I am not fully convinced my work is ok. So I want you to tell me where I am wrong and how to proceed.
I considered a priori a regular pentagon, hence the area is $A = p\cdot a/2$ where $p = 5\ell$ is the perimeter and $\ell$ is the side, and $a$ is the apothem. Now by drawing a regular pentagon, the inscribed circle and the circle inside which the pentagon is inscribed (which is $x^2+y^2 = R^2$), I can write
$$a = \sqrt{R^2 - \frac{\ell^2}{4}} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{4R^2 - \ell^2}$$
Hence the area of the pentagon is $A = \frac{5}{4}\ell \sqrt{4R^2 - \ell^2}$
At this point I thought of Lagrange multipliers:
$$L(R, \ell, \lambda) = \frac{5}{4}\ell\sqrt{4R^2 - \ell^2} - \lambda(x^2+y^2-R^2)$$
I thought to treat $x, y$ as dummy indexes since they don't tell me anything: what matters is the radius $R$ of the exterior circle. And indeed in doing this, setting $\nabla L = 0$ I obtain two equations. After arranging:
$$\begin{cases}4R^2 - 2\ell^2 = 0 \\\\ 10\ell R + 4\lambda R \sqrt{4R^2 - \ell^2} = 0 \end{cases}$$
The first one tells me $\ell = \sqrt{2}R$ and the second one only tells me $\lambda = 5/2$, which is irrelevant.
I indeed obtained the fact that given a random circle of radius $R$, the regular pentagon inscribed in it whose area is the maximum possible needs to have a side of $\sqrt{2}R$.
This seems plausible, but I am in doubt if this is correct at all.
EDIT
I would like to proceed without using angles, sine and cosine, if possible.

But the side of a regular pentagon inscribed in a circle of radius $R$ is $$\ell=2R\sin36°={\sqrt{10-2\sqrt5}\over2}R$$

@Intelligentipauca A difference of $0.23\sim$, cool! Anyway, thank you for this, didn't thought to check. But at this point, what went wrong in my approach? I didn't want to use angles, sine and cosine.

With your method (BTW: Lagrange multipliers were not needed) you found the largest triangle having as sides two radii and a chord of the same circle.

@Intelligentipauca Can you please explain me better? I am really stuck. I mean the function I wanted to maximize is the area of a pentagon. And the constraint was a circle. How this tuned into a triangle?

What you found is the maximum of $f(\ell)={1\over4}\ell\sqrt{4R^2-\ell^2}$, where $\ell$ is the lenght of a chord ($0<\ell<2R$) and $f(\ell)$ is the area of the triangle. It's true you multiplied that by $5$, but that's irrelevant as far as the value of $\ell$ at maximum is concerned.

@Intelligentipauca Ah, thank you! Really didn't think in this optics. Well, then the next question, hoping I don't stress you too much, is: how would we solve the max problem explicitly with Lagrange multipliers? If you believe I should write a new post, tell me!

Yes, I think you'd better ask a new question, exactly stating what you need.

Consider any two consecutive sides $AB$, $BC$ of a convex polygon inscribed in a given circle. Suppose to keep all vertices fixed apart $B$: the area of the polygon is maximum when $B$ is the midpoint of arc $AC$ (distance from $B$ to fixed base $AC$ is maximum).
But that implies $AB=BC$, hence the polygon with maximum area must have any two consecutive sides equal between them, i.e. it must be a regular polygon.


You still have to prove that a maximum exists.

@trula $(S^1)^5$ (or $(D^2)^5$ if you don't assume a priori that the vertices are on the circle but not outside) is compact and the area depends continuously on the five vertices.

@trula: this answer shows clearly that any pentagon that is not regular must have a smaller area than the regular pentagon. Therefore, trivially, the regular pentagon has the maximum possible area.

It is clear , that you can augment every natural number except 1 by taking its square, So it follows, that 1 is the largest number since its square is not larger.

@IntelligentiPauca what software you use to make this geometry image?

@Sahaj I used GeoGebra.

@TonyK Actually, I think trula has a point. This does clearly show if there is a maximal one then it must be regular, and it is highly intuitive. However, the computation could result in an infinite sequence of polygons of increasing area that does not "converge" to a regular polygon. Just that the area goes up by making it a little "closer" to regular.
To close the gap, redistribute the sides with maximal difference to force a limit to a regular polygon, or maybe show that you can bump the area by choosing one of the sides to be the "regular" size, rather than choosing the midpoint.

@ronna If you want to use compactness, there is still a little work to do. You don't get for free that the maximal solution has 5 distinct points, i.e., is a pentagon. It isn't hard to get there, but it must be done.

@nilpotence The argument in this answer does not use that the vertices are distinct, so actually shows that if you have a possibly degenerate pentagon of maximal area then it must be regular. I didn't get pinged because of the misspelling, hence the late response.

Let's look at general (convex) $n$-sided polygons inscribed in a unit circle. Join the centre of the circle to each vertex of the polygon to form $n$ isosceles triangles. Say their apex angles are $\theta_1,\theta_2,\ldots,\theta_n$.
We know that $\sum \theta_i = 2\pi$. The area of the $i\text{th}$ triangle is $\frac12 \sin \theta_i$, so the area of the whole polygon is
$$P=\frac12 \sum \sin \theta_i$$
So we want to maximise $\sum \sin \theta_i$ subject to $\sum \theta_i = 2\pi$, which we can indeed do with a Lagrange multiplier. Let
$$F\left(\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_n,\lambda\right)=\sum \sin \theta_i+\lambda\left(\sum \theta_i - 2\pi\right)$$
Then
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial \theta_i}=\cos \theta_i+\lambda$$
Setting these to zero,
$$\cos \theta_i=-\lambda$$
for every $i$. Without solving the system we can see that this implies all $\theta_i$ are equal; ie the maximum is achieved by a regular polygon.

Thank you! Is there a way to proceed that doesn't involve angles, sine and cosine functions?

+1. But it suffices to apply the Jensen's inequality for the maximization of the function $F$.
